# VB. NET ASPX: find controls triggers and call it dynamically

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am looking for a way, that knowing a controls name,  to raise them or call the processes event/code behind.
I am using VB .NET in VS2010

I have an aspx page with a selection of checkboxes in a panel, each checkbox has its own trigger. I have code that saves a list of checked checkboxes. I have code that restores the checked states to those checkboxes, but I need to execute the associated code to the checkboxes checkchanged event.

```
' Read db to get saved list of checkboxes '
For each result from db
    Dim cb As CheckBox
    cb = 'a function that finds and returns the control'
    ' Now that I have the control, 
    ' how can I find and execute it's checkedchanged code?
```

The control return function is working because in testing, I can process cb.checked = true, and the cb becomes checked, but this doesn't raise the event/trigger the code.

Example of associated checkedchanged subs:

```
Protected Sub cb_use_rc3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cb_use_rc3.CheckedChanged
Protected Sub cb_use_casestatus_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cb_use_casestatus.CheckedChanged
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't call event handler but methods. Write methods for your business-logic that you can call from within the event handler and programmatically.

Comment: I don't necessarily want to call the event handler, I just want to call sub itself. Is that one and the same thing? Sorry my distinction is that those are not one and the same, but I'm likely to be wrong. Once I have retrieved the sub that the objects checkedchanged triggers, I planned to call it via CallByName()

Comment: What are you planning to do in these methods, please be more specific. I'm sure that there's a better approach. Do you want to check the according CheckBoxes?

Comment: Let's say for example: one checkbox is cb_use_rc3. In designer, I double click it and this is created: Protected Sub cb_use_rc3_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles cb_use_rc3.CheckedChanged ,,,, end sub. Within that I have code that enables other controls, refreshes data sources, does stuff related to rc3 fields.

Comment: I have prior code that saved the names of the cb's that were checked. That code is working fine, so lets say, I now have a list of what cb's were checked. I now need to invoke each cb's checkedchanged code, I don't need to trigger checkedchanged, I just need run the code, I assume with callbyname()

Comment: but I do not know how to invoke an associated sub by only knowing the object id it is associated with

Comment: Remove that code from the event-handler completely. Instead create new methods(Subs) for each action. For example `DisplayControls`,`EnableControls`,`LoadData`,`UpdateData` etc. Then you can call these methods with appropriate arguments (f.e. the ID of the record in database and a `Boolean` as argument for `EnableControls`) from the event-handler as well as from wherever you want. This is a much more robust,maintainable,easier, flexible and extensible  approach.

Comment: Thank you, I'll get back to this on Monday when back in the office.

Comment: thank you, I had hoped an answer would not involve adding more blocks of code, resigning that I had no choice, I spent the day going through and creating 1 function: cb_handling(controlname as string) containing a if controlname = ### for every cb on the page and placed the code from each handle event into the 'if' block. in the handler code, I added a call to the function. More work than desired, but I suppose it is easier to call each check boxes code behind now. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm working on the assumption that your checkboxes each have an individual ID and are not generated by a bound control of any sort.

While it is possible to determine what handler is hooked up to what event of what object (or so I understand), it's probably more trouble than it's worth for this limited case.

The simplest, though ugliest, way to do it would be this:

1. Follow Mr. Schmelter's advice and isolate the business logic in meaningfully-named methods.  Call them from each event handler rather than putting all the logic in the event handler.
2. Since you have the control, you can determine its ID.  Use a `Select Case` statement with the ID of the control to determine which method or methods from #1 to call.

Comment: Each checkbox does indeed have it's own unique id. Each is hard coded in the aspx, no dynamically added controls.

Comment: Thanks Ann, I think I took the essence of Tim and your suggestions and now have it functioning.  I was focused on a few line solution and never stood back and looked at rewriting the core of what i had already completed.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
For Each grd_Row As GridViewRow In gvPersonalInventario.Rows
  Dim cb As New Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox
  cb = grd_Row.FindControl("CheckBox2")
  If cb.Checked = True Then
    label1.text = grd_Row.Cells(0).Text
  End If
Next
```